# Is there a way to access the logging level of a connector in Mule 4?

Tags: mule, mulesoft, mule-component, mule4

I wonder if there is a way to access the current logging level of a connector in Mule 4.

e.g., I have configured an Logger:

[image]

Is there a way to get the level configured for it?

Comment: What are "connector properties" in this context?

Comment: Need More information what is expected. Question is not clear

Comment: I wish somehow (maybe using dataweave) I could get the level value: "INFO". like: #[logger.level] outputs me the value "INFO"

Comment: Why exactly do you need to get it?

Comment: I wish I could run some logic based on this condition, @aled

Comment: Sorry, that's not very helpful to understand what you are trying to do. What kind of logic do you want to execute based on logging level? Are you trying to "inject" some custom logging based on the logging level?

Comment: we have a different dw functions/scripts to log for each logger category. although I could manually set each set each one, it could be easier if I could get this information dinamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing "connector properties" with logging configuration. Don't try to access directly to information you see in the debugger. That's just not how it works and it is undocumented at best.

The logging configuration is not a connector configuration but a per Java class property. I don't believe it available for easy retrieval from a flow.